# Can I be rewarded for discovering, creating, and proving bugs on Bitcoin?

Tags: private-key, public-key, signature, raw-transaction, cryptography

There has never been a remittance history to this address.
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/1JqPFnGPhHhy54zJKmC1MPiczzgFjCmzE9
public key : 02f51f8d0c4dc4a5338bef745098e6f6364f8936fee6aa5a9d4ab0c214e7cdd727

It has a balance of 340 bitcoins.
I am not the owner of this bitcoin.
However, you can create a transaction with only the public key.
I can make this kind of transaction infinite.

You can check the rsz value with this program.

https://github.com/Sean-Bradley/ECDSA_secp256k1_JordonMatrix_nodejs/blob/master/getPubKeyFromRSZ.py
[image]

R = 0xf8eb13edf4663f68fe635bdd7222c79d964099b4bb7595a53e1c22f988c1cfa2
S = 0xd83fd6c056a6eae6f76c492f7791fdb83336a5b796aa95656159e161cf1d03bc
Z = 0x72ee6ef84536396d0b655396281876a81cd998bb27dde49171785a6c4c45e6e7

R = 0xb4684517444a86cbc7a11eeda7aea984755dbb624d57907f09dcc4e47bd648cd
S = 0xcdffc4fb64e5acd079b2c3de7c8c122a7a4cdfb9f70cc02eef54452bbf5e7b82
Z = 0x873b1235044c5b38a24cfa941cb6347ba6038771d54b672e03d812fc291dffa2

R = 0x4e3a352bd5f7598ddf580f5e2181ea3faf33e8186dff84aa462d90b3b37e7371
S = 0xaad1fce91c3326b6ad8dc1c0a0d41625ec23b97f4f50092d94b36f22b3c1122d
Z = 0x8625e67ceca36f11d315be232fe86bef50c4d8a6bcf9fc4adb7120fb671bc827

R = 0xd875063a0b9e9aa30d58f8ac3e39d1f6695a5d04deea0a8f1d6dcbc96a3a3d22
S = 0xbe27760132ba69321cb938ab931fd78ce9c944644505b48ae170e8171ccfe761
Z = 0xdeead39249eb7d02856de81723d193727a599db0a156dbf5bff60427d17f5a95

R = 0x29e690606edf3d7dc5b2e4f83c2c7ea8924cb0911792514c1912789cc3dde563
S = 0xc7722f325ce71add08eb51e9edfae276d9c164d298d8355c6cf75359e5cf7eb3
Z = 0x5c7abfcb68f3e4d0320c760a8430a52c90d8c2ee3795878b0b308bfaa310082f

Answer (score 5):

Yes, finding bugs in Bitcoin would be valuable. However this doesn't seem to be one.

What's shown here is a series of supposed "signatures" with the *hashes of messages* they supposedly sign. However, **a cryptographic signature is only meaningful in the context of the *message* it signs.**

To [verify a signature](https://cryptobook.nakov.com/digital-signatures/ecdsa-sign-verify-messages#ecdsa-verify-signature), you need three inputs: 1) the message, 2) the public key, and 3) the signature. Generating a "signature" that corresponds to a public key is trivial if it doesn't need to match a message, but without the message it cannot be verified to be a *valid* signature.

To create a Bitcoin transaction, you need to sign a specific message, namely the transaction. If you could do that, that would be a problem, however, that's not what you've shown here. Rather than the message, you only provide the hash of a message of which you do not know the preimage—a parlor trick.